# Parsing JSON by python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have problem with it. 
I need to get 2 items in JSON Items is "some_number" and "some_number_2"
Items "sample1" and "sample2" in every request various. 
I'm new person in Python. Thank you so much

```
"data":{
   "sample1":{
      "some_number":"8410000110275080",
      "some_number_2":"0070050001010011",
      "name":"0000405533003537",
      },
   "sample2":{
      "some_number":"8410000110275080",
      "some_number_2":"0070050001010011",
      "name":"0000405533003537",
      }
```

In my code I just can earn 'sample1' and 'sample2'. In next request this values is various.

Comment: This isn't valid json. Are there outer braces wrapping `data`?

Comment: There's a bultin `json` module you can use. `data = json.load(fd); [(d['some_number'], d['some_number_2']) for _,d in data['data'].items()]` ?  Don't use one liners though :)

Comment: How are you trying to store your values for `some_number` and `some_number_2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the Json in a dictionnary:

```
with open("your file path", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Then, if you want to iterate over both keys and values of the dictionnary, do this:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print key, value
```

You can then nest `for` loop to get the desired `key, value` pairs.

Best

Comment: Well, there are many things to note here. Your code will NOT work with JSON data posted above. Secondly, if we believe the input data is in correct format then are you sure this answer is not a dupe?

Comment: The Json posted above has `,` that have nothing to do here but this code works with a well-formatted json. Then, I'm just giving an hint on how to solve the problem. He/her will better lean how to manipulate Json if he/her has to think on how to get values.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your json file looks like:

```
{"data":{
   "sample1":{
      "some_number":"8410000110275080",
      "some_number_2":"0070050001010011",
      "name":"0000405533003537",
      },
   "sample2":{
      "some_number":"8410000110275080",
      "some_number_2":"0070050001010011",
      "name":"0000405533003537",
      }
}
```

You can parse it using something like the json module:

```py
import json

# open the file using with
with open('myfile.json') as fh:
    my_json = json.load(fh)

# Now my_json is a dictionary
# We can iterate over values of a dictionary
inner_dict = my_json['data']

some_number, some_number_2 = [], []

# Iterate over each value
for val in inner_dict.values():
    some_number.append(val['some_number'])
    some_number_2.append(val['some_number_2'])
```